# pcregrep a wiggle file to extract chromosome. Multiple line regex search

Tags: regex, sed, grep, bioinformatics

I wrote a simple regular expression to use with pcregrep to return a given chromosome within a wiggle file (see below).

```
 pcregrep -M '^fixedStep chrom=2.*\n[0-9\n]*' input.txt
```

Input.wig

```
fixedStep chrom=1 start=14154 step=1
1
1
1
1
1
fixedStep chrom=2 start=14154 step=1
1
1
3
10
120
14
5
9
fixedStep chrom=2 start=20145 step=1
1
1
11
1
1
fixedStep chrom=2 start=30535 step=1
3
24
11
fixedStep chrom=3 start=14154 step=1
1
1
1
1
1
```

the output is:

```
fixedStep chrom=2 start=14154 step=1
1
1
3
10
120
14
5
9
fixedStep chrom=2 start=30124 step=1
fixedStep chrom=2 start=50345 step=1
4
23
90
fixedStep chrom=3 start=14154 step=1
```

but what I would like to get is:

```
fixedStep chrom=2 start=14154 step=1
1
1
3
10
120
14
5
9
fixedStep chrom=2 start=20145 step=1
1
1
11
1
1
fixedStep chrom=2 start=30535 step=1
3
24
11
```

More specifically I would like to find each entry within the file matching

```
fixedStep chrom=2 start=ANY step=1
1
2
3
4
```

and remove it, while keeping all other chromosomes.

EDIT:

I partially solved the search problem; I can use

```
pcregrep -M '^fixed.*chrom=2.*(\n[0-9]+)*' input.txt
```

to get the correct output; but I still haven't found an efficient way to remove chromosome 2 from input.txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use `awk`? Is so then this should work:

```
awk '/chrom=2/{p=1}/chrom=[^2]/{p=0}p' input
```

Comment: What about the opposite of that? How do I remove every chromo=2 entry and keep everything else?

Comment: Just reverse the values of `p`. `awk '/chrom=2/{p=0}/chrom=[^2]/{p=1}p' input`